# Hide dock tab in Android Studio by hotkey

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, android-studio, ide, hotkeys

I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 on mac.

When <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> pop the documentation, how can I use hotkey to hide it?
(Press F1 again doesn't hide it)

[image]

At the top right of the image, I wonder what is the key after `Shift`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the area.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the title bar can hide the tab.

So I guess the icon [image] might not be a key, it means click.